# Material not showing correctly

Tags: three.js

I'm having an issue where the material is not showing correctly. I checked the MTL file and all looks correct but for some reason, the material seems to be flipped(I can see it through some parts while it should be the screen). Initially I thought there was something wrong with the MTL or the OBJ but here comes the funny part. On 3dviewer.net the model looks completely perfect(last screenshot).
Therefore, does anybody have a clue on what's happening?

[image: front]
[image: Inside view]
[image: 3dviewer]

Answer (score 1):

By default, Three.js only renders the front side of faces, since there's often no reason to render the inside of objects. The problem is that the asset you've exported has the face of the screen pointing inwards. There are two ways of solving this problem:

1. Open the asset in a 3D editor, flip the direction of the faces that are pointing inward, and re-export.
2. You could change the default [`material.side` attribute](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.side) of your material. My best guess is that: `material.side = THREE.BackSide` would solve your problem, but you could try the other values in that documentation page.

Comment: The second option really worked well! Thank you so much! I was going a bit nuts with it.
I'm not sure yet how to do option 1(since I just have the obj + mtl) but if you have any app as tip, would be really appreciated. I'm experiencing a simular issue with a-frame, so I can imagine I will have to find a similar solution...